# How to transfer NSdata from one iphone to another

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I go about transferring a NSData object from 1 iphone to another? (It is an audio which I am looking to play out of iphone #2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are various ways to achieve this.

My suggestion would be to look at Apple's [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html) library. This makes it trivial to establish a connection to another iOS device. You may connect via Bluetooth or Wifi (if all you need to do is 'trigger' a sound that already exists in the application bundle on both devices, bluetooth will work fine - if you actually need to transfer a sound file, you probably want to use a Wifi connection). You will have to implement the actual transmission mechanism/protocol yourself in either case.

Another option is to use Bonjour and pass your data over TCP/IP.

You may find this tutorial helpful:
[Networking and Bonjour on iPhone](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html) framework, you can use bluetooth to send data between iOS devices. Take a look at the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Options:
1. Gamekit Framework
2. Look at the open source application "Bump"